# paperclip content type for xls and xlsx

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

struggling with paperclip content type, need to upload xls/xlsx file.

```
has_attached_file :sheet
validates_attachment_content_type :sheet, content_type: [
                                          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                          'application/zip',
                                          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                                          'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                          'application/xls',
                                          'application/xlsx',
                                          'application/octet-stream'
                                        ],
                                message: ' Only EXCEL files are allowed.'
```

**NOTE:** Created a sheet from google drive.

Above content types i tried but every time got the same error

Output

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/zy/khy_wsfn7jbd40bsdps7qwqc0000gt/T/5a76e813d6a0a40548b91acc11557bd220160328-13642-1meqjap.xlsx'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/zy/khy_wsfn7jbd40bsdps7qwqc0000gt/T/5a76e813d6a0a40548b91acc11557bd220160328-13642-114d8t6.xlsx'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
{:sheet_content_type=>[" Only EXCEL files are allowed."], :sheet=>[" Only EXCEL files are allowed."]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed the path  ; (

Fixed it by using

```
has_attached_file :sheet,
                :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:filename"

validates_attachment :sheet, presence: true,
                   content_type: { content_type: [
                     "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                   ]
                   },
                   message: ' Only EXCEL files are allowed.'
```

Comment: What does the path have to do with anything? It works for DOC without the path. Why not XLS? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927006/paperclip-cannot-attach-xls-but-doc-works

Comment: `:path` isn't even an option! http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file