# Paperclip: Cannot attach XLS (But DOC works)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mime-types, paperclip-validation

I cannot attach a XLS file, but DOC works:

> Attachments file content type is invalid
>   Attachments file is invalid

Here is the log:

```
Parameters: ... "files"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000daf7730 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170511-47156-ym774u.xls>, @original_filename="Chocolate_Store1.xls", @content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"deal[files][]\"; filename=\"Chocolate_Store1.xls\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">],
...
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/1f1fb4d71efc0bd245abd7b5b9aa661220170511-47156-1rqzd0q.xls"
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering deals/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
```

When I test the type:

```
>file -b --mime "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/1f1fb4d71efc0bd245abd7b5b9aa661220170511-47156-1rqzd0q.xls"
application/vnd.ms-office; charset=binary
```

I have this type in my accept list:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :file
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: [
    "application/pdf", "application/msword", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "application/vnd.ms-office",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
   ]

end
```

Rails 5.0.2, Paperclip 5.1.0, File 5.04 (DevKit)

---

I noticed DevKit `file` differs from Cygwin `file`. Not sure if relevant:

```
>file -b --mime "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/1f1fb4d71efc0bd245abd7b5b9aa661220170515-54920-1e2bk5s.xls"
application/vnd.ms-office; charset=binary

$ file -b --mime "C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/1f1fb4d71efc0bd245abd7b5b9aa661220170515-54920-1e2bk5s.xls"
application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=binary
```

Comment: I guess you should simply add `application/vnd.ms-office` (as the `file` command suggests) to the list of supported content types in your validation definition?

Comment: @BoraMa No that doesn't work. I tried to add that but it still won't accept XLS files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched to use

```
validates_attachment_file_name :file, matches: [/\.pdf$/, /\.docx?$/, /\.xlsx?$/, /\.odt$/, /\.ods$/]
```

Comment: Cool answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
...content_type: [...'application/x-ole-storage'...]
```

worked for me